# Compare two geometry tables using PostGIS

Tags: postgis

I have two geometries tables and I want to do a comparison between them two, so that I be able to select from one the geometries that don't exist  in the second. To do so I conceived the usage of  the following query :

```
create table touches_diammat_exists as select 
touches_diammat.* from touches_diammat,pipe 
where  st_astext(touches_diammat.fusion) != st_astext(pipe.geom)
```

Yet the results I'm getting have nothing to do with what I was expecting. It gave me a lot of geometries to the pace of a few. I don't know, I'm so confused and I even can't find  what I'm missing in my query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PostGIS has a function for comparing two geometries: `st_equals()`

But this is not the problem here. Rather a problem that you did not understand the basics of joining tables.

You're joining two tables, meaning that you will receive the same record of the first table for every pipe.geom that does not match that geom.

You can match the id's that **do match** in a subquery and use `WHERE id NOT IN matches`.

```
SELECT *
FROM touches_diammat
WHERE id NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT t.id
    FROM touches_diammat t
    JOIN pipe p
    ON st_equals(t.fusion, p.geom)
) matches;
```

Comment: I wonder if a simple `LEFT OUTER JOIN` wouldn't be faster than a`NOT IN` subquery.